# Determine the likelihood of occurrence of an activity within a subset

Tags: probability, subset

I have a monitor that measures dust concentrations around our neighborhood, and from this dataset I subset it into three scenarios to see which scenarios create the most dust. However, when I do this, the subsets have various sample sizes (i.e different amount of hours when those activities occurred, which is expected).
How do I compare which scenario is more likely to cause high level of dust?

Example below:

```
Recorded data has sample size of 1000 hours. 
    Subset 1 (General car movements only) - 700 hours 
    Subset 2 (Construction vehicles movement + general car movement) - 200 hours 
    Subset 3 (Road closure with no vehicle movement) - 100 hours

Number of hours exceeded dust concentration X amount which I set to determine if the activity 
is dusty:

    Subset 1  - 100 hours 
    Subset 2  - 50 hours 
    Subset 3  - 10 hours

The % of exceedance occurrence for each subset is:
    Subset 1 - 100/160*100 = 63%
    Subset 2 - 50/160*100 = 31%
    Subset 3  - 10/160*100 = 6%
```

But I don't think I can say that Subset 1 is more likely to cause high number of dust since its sample size is 500 hours more than Subset 2...
I have very minimal statistic knowledge and would really appreciate to receive any guidance on how to address this :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There a few simply statistical tests you can do here. If you have the null hypothesis $H_0$: likelihood of high dust levels in a given hour is unrelated to the subset the hour belongs to, with the alternative hypothesis being $H_A$: the likelihood of high dust levels in a given hour is related to the subset the hour belongs to, then one approach to test this is with a chi-square test of independence. For the example you gave I performed this test and found there was indeed a statistically significant relation between subset and likelihood of high dust levels, with higher dust levels occuring during construction. See the test output below:

[image]